# React, ordering and array of objects (reduce and map?)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapreduce, javascript-objects

the issue is as follows: (https://codesandbox.io/s/8p21n6p09l)

I've got an array of objects (called modules) that looks like that:

```
const modules = [
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 1",
    id: 1,
    name: "Budowanie postawy asertywnej",
    details: [
      "Czym jest asertywność?",
      "Asertywny Asertywny menedżer – charakterystyczne zachowania"
    ]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 2",
    id: 2,
    name: "Asertywne narzędzia",
    details: [
      "Asertywna odmowa – zastosowanie trzyetapowej procedury",
      "Technika „Zdartej płyty”",
      "Wyrażanie pochwał i próśb"        ]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 3",
    id: 3,
    name: "Lorem ipsum 1",
    details: ["Coś się wymyśli", "Żeby nie było tak łyso"]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 3",
    id: 4,
    name: "Lorem ipsum 2",
    details: [
      "Wyczesane szkolenia",
      "Naprawdępowinieneś wrzucić to do koszyka",
      "Na co czekasz - dodaj!"
    ]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 3",
    id: 5,
    name: "Ipsum Lorem",
    details: ["Och", "Ach"]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 3",
    id: 6,
    name: "Ipsum Lorem 1",
    details: ["Och", "Ach"]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 3",
    id: 7,
    name: "Ipsum Lorem 2",
    details: ["Och", "Ach"]
  },
```

and this array is passed from App.js to thmaticArea.jsx component. The thing is that I've changed my mind in displaying data and want group them by thematicArea, so it'd look like:

```
Topic 1: 
 - Name 1
 - Name 2
 - Name 6
 - ...
Topic 2:
 - Name 3
 - Name 5
Topic 3:
- Name 4
and so on.
```

Each Name is unique and can have only one thematicArea (Topic) but one thematicArea (Topic) can have multiple names (Name 1, Name 2...).

I believe I should use reduce() method first and .map() then, but I've tried it in multiple ways and it doesn't worked for me. Reduce() method is creating an array with no length... This is how I tried to implement it with reduce in App.js and pass it to thematicArea.jsx component as 'modules':

```
modules={this.state.modules.reduce(function(groups, item) {
              const val = item["thematicArea"];
              groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
              groups[val].push(item);
              return groups;
            }, [])}
```

What is the best way to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't a theoretical programming question I think the best way is to use _.groupBy from lodash or similar. Reinventing the wheel in not needed sometimes.

Comment: Ok, I admit that it is ridiculusly the simplest way to order it! I don't know why i Didn't think about Lodash! Thanks for this but...
Still got an object that I want to map(), so I should use Object.keys atfirst but the result is only like names of thematicArea without any further data connected to each. How shall I cope with that issue?

Comment: Take a look to lodash docs, it's easy to find methods that do complex operations in  comfortable way. You can simply iterate the object keys and keep what you want to keep with _.pick()

Answer (score 0):

I have an example with an object or an array at the end.

Is this what you want?

```js
const modules = [{
    thematicArea: "Topic 1",
    id: 1,
    name: "Budowanie postawy asertywnej",
    details: [
      "Czym jest asertywność?",
      "Asertywny Asertywny menedżer – charakterystyczne zachowania"
    ]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 2",
    id: 2,
    name: "Asertywne narzędzia",
    details: [
      "Asertywna odmowa – zastosowanie trzyetapowej procedury",
      "Technika „Zdartej płyty”",
      "Wyrażanie pochwał i próśb"
    ]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 3",
    id: 3,
    name: "Lorem ipsum 1",
    details: ["Coś się wymyśli", "Żeby nie było tak łyso"]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 3",
    id: 4,
    name: "Lorem ipsum 2",
    details: [
      "Wyczesane szkolenia",
      "Naprawdępowinieneś wrzucić to do koszyka",
      "Na co czekasz - dodaj!"
    ]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 3",
    id: 5,
    name: "Ipsum Lorem",
    details: ["Och", "Ach"]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 3",
    id: 6,
    name: "Ipsum Lorem 1",
    details: ["Och", "Ach"]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 3",
    id: 7,
    name: "Ipsum Lorem 2",
    details: ["Och", "Ach"]
  },
];

// If you want the values in an object
const retObject = modules.reduce((tmp, x) => {
  if (!tmp[x.thematicArea]) {
    tmp[x.thematicArea] = [x.name];
  } else {
    tmp[x.thematicArea].push(x.name);
  }

  return tmp;
}, {});

console.log('Value as object -----');
console.log(retObject);

// If you want the values in array
const retArray = Object.values(retObject);

console.log('Value as array -----');
console.log(retArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this way and final output should be `object` not `array`.

```js
const modules = [{
        thematicArea: "Topic 1",
        id: 1,
        name: "Budowanie postawy asertywnej",
        details: [
            "Czym jest asertywność?",
            "Asertywny Asertywny menedżer – charakterystyczne zachowania"
        ]
    },
    {
        thematicArea: "Topic 2",
        id: 2,
        name: "Asertywne narzędzia",
        details: [
            "Asertywna odmowa – zastosowanie trzyetapowej procedury",
            "Technika „Zdartej płyty”",
            "Wyrażanie pochwał i próśb"
        ]
    },
    {
        thematicArea: "Topic 3",
        id: 3,
        name: "Lorem ipsum 1",
        details: ["Coś się wymyśli", "Żeby nie było tak łyso"]
    },
    {
        thematicArea: "Topic 3",
        id: 4,
        name: "Lorem ipsum 2",
        details: [
            "Wyczesane szkolenia",
            "Naprawdępowinieneś wrzucić to do koszyka",
            "Na co czekasz - dodaj!"
        ]
    },
    {
        thematicArea: "Topic 3",
        id: 5,
        name: "Ipsum Lorem",
        details: ["Och", "Ach"]
    },
    {
        thematicArea: "Topic 3",
        id: 6,
        name: "Ipsum Lorem 1",
        details: ["Och", "Ach"]
    },
    {
        thematicArea: "Topic 3",
        id: 7,
        name: "Ipsum Lorem 2",
        details: ["Och", "Ach"]
    }
];



let result = modules.reduce((obj, val) => {
    obj[val.thematicArea] = obj[val.thematicArea] || [];
    if (obj[val.thematicArea].indexOf(val.name) == -1)
        obj[val.thematicArea].push(val.name);
    return obj;
}, {});


console.log(result);
```

Comment: But than I need to map this object. I can't use Object.keys because it looses all it's further data connected to each element (results only Topic 1, Topic 2, Topic3 without any data connected to that).